# 'be inherent in' VS 'belong to'

Tags: word-usage

What is the subtle difference between 'be inherent in' and 'belong to'? Can I use the latter to replace the former in most situations? What does the 'inherent' try to emphasise?

Comment: Where did you see *inherent in* meaning "belonging to"? They are [quite different](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inherent).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Belong to' may mean either 'be a constituent / member / example of' or 'be owned by' etc.

> [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/belong-to)
>   gives:
>
> **1 belong to someone** to be owned by someone
>
> *The car belongs to the woman next door.*
>
> *Who does this coat belong to?*
>
> ***3 belong to something** to come from or be part of a group of similar things or people
>
> *This belongs to the same family of drugs as Prozac.*
>
> *They belong to a different generation.*
>
> [*'*belong to a club*' is really a sub-sense of this]

You can't replace 'belong to' with 'be inherent in' when the ownership sense is in play, as with 'This house belongs to the Davies'.

........

However, 'is/are inherent in' may on occasion be replaced by 'belong/s to'.

*This property belongs to / is inherent to all the noble gases.*

I certainly wouldn't do so, though, with every example using the 'existing as a natural or basic part of something' sense:

*There are dangers/risks inherent in almost every sport.* [[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inherent)]

*'The potential for change that is inherent in the political world'*; 'is present in' is correct here.